# Advantages and disadvantages of single numeric (float) data type

Tags: math, floating-point, int, computer-science, precision

Why we use various data types in programming languages ? Why not use float everywhere ? I have heard some arguments like

1. Arithmetic on **int** is faster ( but why ?)
2. It takes more memory to store float. ( I get it.)

What are the additional benefits of using various types of numeric data types ?

Answer (score 2):

Arithmetic on integers has traditionally been faster because it's a simpler operation. It can be implemented in logic gates and, if properly designed, the whole thing can happen in a single clock cycle.

On most modern PCs floating-point support is actually quite fast, because loads of time has been invested into *making* it fast. It's only on lower-end processors (like Arduino, or some versions of the ARM platform) where floating point seriously suffers, or is absent from the CPU altogether.

A floating point number contains a few different pieces of data: there's a sign bit, and the mantissa, and the exponent. To put those three parts together to determine the value they represent, you do something like this:

```
value = sign * mantissa * 2^exponent
```

It's a little more complicated than that because floating point numbers optimize how they store the mantissa a bit (for instance the first bit of the mantissa is assumed to be 1, thus the first bit doesn't actually need to be stored...  But this also means zero has to be stored a particular way, and there's various "special values" that can be stored in floats like "not a number" and infinity that have to be handled correctly when working with floats)

So to store the number "3" you'd have a mantissa of 0.75 and an exponent of 2. (0.75 * 2^2 = 3).

But then to add two floats together, you first have to align them. For instance, 3 + 10:

```
m3 = 0.75  (stored as binary (1)1000000...  the first (1) implicit and not actually stored)
e3 = 2
m10 = .625  (stored as binary (1)010000...)
e10 = 4     (.625 * 2^4 = 10)
```

You can't just add m3 and m10 together, 'cause you'd get the wrong answer. You first have to shift m3 over by a couple bits to get e3 and e10 to match, then you can add the mantissas together and reassemble the result into a new floating point number. A CPU with good floating-point implementation will do all that for you, of course, and do it fast.

So why else would you not want to use floating point values for everything? Well, for starters there's the problem of *exactness*. If you add or multiply two integers to get another integer, as long as you don't exceed the limits of your integer size, the answer you get will be *exactly* correct. This isn't the case with floating-point. For instance:

```
x = 1000000000.0
y = .0000000001
for (cc = 0; cc < 1000000000; cc++) { x += y; }
```

Logically you'd expect the final value of (x) to be 1000000000.1, but that's almost certainly not what you're going to get. When you add (y) to (x), the change to (x)'s mantissa may be so small that it doesn't even fit into the float, and so (x) may not change at all. And even if that's not the case, (y)'s value is not exact. There are no two integers (a, b) such that (a * 2^b = 10^-10). That's true for many common decimal values, actually. Even something simple like 0.3 can't be stored as an exact value in a binary floating-point number.

So (y) isn't exactly 10^-10, it's actually off by some small amount. For a 32-bit floating point number it'll be off by about 10^-26:

```
y = 10^-10 + error, error is about 10^-26
```

Then if you add (y) together ten billion times, the error is magnified by about ten billion times as well, so your final error is around 10^-16

A good floating-point implementation will try to minimize these errors, but it can't always get it right. The problem is fundamental to how the numbers are stored, and to some extent unavoidable. As a result, for instance, even though it seems natural to store a money value in a float, it might be preferable to store it as an integer instead, to get that assurance that the value is always exact.

The "exactness" issue also means that when you test the value of a floating point number, generally speaking, you can't use exact comparisons. For instance:

```
x = 11.0 / 500
if (x * 50 == 1.1) { ...  It doesn't!

for (float x = 0.0; x < 1.0; x += 0.01) { print x; }
// prints 101 values instead of 100, the last one being 0.9999999...
```

The test fails because (x) isn't exactly the value we specified, and 1.1, when encoded as a float, isn't exactly the value we specified either. They're both *close* but not *exact*. So you have to do inexact comparisons:

```
if (abs(x - expected_value) < small_value) {...
```

Choosing the correct "small_value" is a problem unto itself. It can depend on what you're doing with the values, what kind of behavior you're trying to achieve.

Finally, if you look at the "it takes more memory" issue, you can also turn that around and think of it in terms of what you *get* for the memory you use.

If you can work with integer math for your problem, a 32-bit unsigned integer lets you work with (exact) values between 0 and around 4 billion.

If you're using 32-bit floats instead of 32-bit integers, you can store larger values than 4 billion, but you're still limited by the representation: of those 32 bits, one is used for the sign bit, and eight for the mantissa, so you get 23 bits (24, effectively) of mantissa. Once (x >= 2^24), you're beyond the range where integers are stored "exactly" in that float, so (x+1 = x). So a loop like this:

```
float i;
for (i = 1600000; i < 1700000; i += 1);
```

would never terminate: (i) would reach (2^24 = 16777216), and the least-significant bit of its mantissa would be of a magnitude greater than 1, so adding 1 to (i) would cease to have any effect.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: This is very misleading; integer operations on floats are exact as long as the absolute value of the result does not exceed 2^53.  You are comparing apples and oranges here.